# Is the length of the composition series of a free module identical to the number of its bases?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, graded-modules, graded-rings

> Let $A_0$ be an Artinian ring, $M$ a free $A_0$-module. Then, is the length of the composition series of $M$ identical to the number of its bases?

It seems to me that it is not. If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $A_0$ and $e$ is a basis of $M$ then ${\mathfrak a}e$ is a submodule of $A_0 e$. Therefore the chain has to have the length more than the number of bases. But I know I'm wrong, because there is an example shown in  *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and McDonald:

> Let $A=A_0[x_1,\cdots,x_s]$, where $A_0$ is an Artinian ring and the $x_i$ are independent indeterminates. Then $A_n$ is a free $A_0$-module generated by the monomials $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_s^{m_s}$ where $\sum m_i =n$; there are 
>   $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} s+n-1 \\ s-1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$
>   of these, hence $P(A,t)=(1-t)^{-s}$.

The Poincaré series $P(M,t)$ is defined for a finitely-generated graded $A$-module $M$ 
($A$ is a Noetherian graded ring) and an additive function $\lambda$ as follows:

$$
P(M,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(M_n) t^n \;\; \in {\mathbb Z}[[t]].
$$

In the example, $\lambda(M)$ is the length $l(M)$ of a finitely-generated $A_0$-module $M$.

What is wrong with my reasoning ?

Comment: What are the $A_n$?

Comment: $A$ is a Noetherian graded ring $A=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty A_n$. $M$ is a finitely-generated graded $A$-module $M=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty M_n$.

Comment: In the example, $A_n$ is the set of the homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$.

Comment: Okay, it seems to me that you are right. For $λ(M) = l(M)/l(A)$ it’ll work, though, wouldn’t it?

Comment: It works. Then, the description of the example in this famous book is not correct. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me on which page you have found this? And can you tell me which version of Commutative Algebra you have? So I can look up to see if I have the same wording.

Comment: It is the page 118 of 1969 version.

Comment: Thank you. I have the same issue (and therefore the same wording).