# Example 11.3 in Atiyah Macdonald book

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Look at this problem: [Is the length of the composition series of a free module identical to the number of its bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749283/is-the-length-of-the-composition-series-of-a-free-module-identical-to-the-number)

I wanna confirm that the example is false or correct. Moreover, if it is incorrect, is $P(M,t)=l(A_{0})(1-t)^{-s}$ right? because of $l(A_{n})=l(A_{0})\binom{n+s-1}{s-1}$ (*).

Can you prove (*)? This equation is still true if $A_{0}$ is not Artin in this case.

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/163121/23950

Comment: Can you help me prove that equation?

Answer (score 1):

I give the answer to close this topic.

$R_{n}=\oplus_{\sum_{m_{i}}=n} (R_{0}x_{1}^{m_{1}}...x_{r}^{m_{r}})\Rightarrow l(R_{n})=\oplus_{\sum_{m_{i}}=n} l(R_{0}x_{1}^{m_{1}}...x_{r}^{m_{r}})$

$\Rightarrow l(R_{n})=l(R_{0})|x_{1}^{m_{1}}...x_{r}^{m_{r}}|_{\sum_{m_{i}}=n}=l(R_{0})\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$